# Increasing understanding of the Python read() and open() functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using the read() and open() functions whilst using Python 3.7

Is there a reason that `open()` is documented but `read()` is not?

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print(f"Here's your file {filename}:")
print(txt.read())

print("Type the filename again:")
file_again = input("> ")

txt_again = open(file_again)

print(txt_again.read())
```

Comment: read is not a built in function. There's a read method on file objects though

Comment: Then why can I utilise it in a Python 3.7 installation?

Comment: How are you using it? Show us sample code

Comment: `open()` is an in-built function, whereas `read()` is not. It's but a function on file handler. You do `<file_handler>.read()` not just `read()`.

Comment: Sample code provided.

Comment: Your code does not show you using read as a standalone function.

Comment: How is that the case? I am calling read() on it's own

Comment: Look again, you really aren't. The only thing you do is `txt.read()` and `txt_again.read()`.

Comment: Sorry perhaps you can help me here. What is your definition of a standalone function? I'm quickly becoming confused.

In this script I understand that I am using the read() and open() functions and passing arguments to them.

Comment: Can you really not tell the difference between `open(filename)` and `txt.read()`? Contrary to your assertion, you don't pass any arguments to `read()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `read` is not a built-in [function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-function), but a [method](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method) of [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) (`*IO*` / `*Reader`).

You can find documetations of such `read` methods: [`io.RawIOBase.read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.read), [`io.BufferedIOBase.read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.read), [`io.BufferedReader.read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader.read), [`io.TextIOBase.read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.read), ...

Comment: Where can I find this documented on the Python website? I expect on doing a Google search 'Python open() function' to find the right official docs listed

Comment: @user1554264, About `open`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: @user1554264, In `open` documentation, you can follow `file-object` documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object

Comment: @user1554264, `file-object` glossary contains `io` module documentation (which contains description of  `*IOBase`s, `*Reader`, ...)  https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#module-io

Answer (score 4):

Because `read()` is NOT a built-in function, as it's not present as `builtins.read`. Instead, it's a method of `_io.BufferedReader` class. That means you have to create an object of that class (usually with the built-in function `open()`), and call `read()` for the object.

Comment: So am I correct in saying I would not be able to call read() before open() as I have not instantiated an object of that class?

Comment: @user1554264 Or more precisely, you don't *have an instance* (note: `sys.stdin` is an object that has `read()`, which is automatically opened)

Comment: I'm learning from a Python book that was recommended to me, however the language the author uses is fairly concerning - 'Line 7 prints a little message, but on line 8 we have something very new and exciting. We call a function on txt named read. What you get back from open is a file, and it also has commands you can give it.' It doesn't feel exhaustive or technical enough, in other words feels like I'm learning the wrong stuff from it.

Answer (score 0):

Because `read()` is a method of a `file-object`

Answer (score 0):

`read` is not a Python as others have said. It's a method that you will find for many I/O object such as file objects, http requests, and more.